# Is primitive type to string a widening conversion?

Tags: vb.net

I understand that an integer is a 32 bit data type and a long is a 64 bit data type etc.  How many bits is a string?

Is an implicit cast from a primitive type to a string always a widening cast?
For example, please see the code below:

```
Public sub routine1(byval strParam as string)

End sub

Public sub routine2()

    Dim intTest As Integer
    intTest = 1
    routine1(intTest)

End sub
```

Would this always be safe to do regardless of whether intTest was a:  boolean, int, long, decimal etc (all the primitive types).

In another question an answerer said: "Not everything necessarily has a perfectly accurate string representation that is also the one you want to use,".  When they say "not everything", I believe they are referring to custom types e.g. Foo, where you have to override .ToString().  Is this correct.

The question is: is it always safe to implicilty cast from a primitive type to a string?

Comment: What do you mean by "safe"? That depends on what you want to do with the string value. In general, to be "safe" (and maintainable), be explicit about what you want the result of a conversion to be. In most languages, the "most default" conversion of an integer to a string will *probably* give you a decimal representation, which is *probably* reasonable in most situations, but if you have an integer and the method you're calling wants a string, you need to be specific about how to do the conversion.

Answer (score 0):

The method/sub named **routine1** accepts a string argument. Trying to pass any other object will invoke the ToString method of that object.
Since the **Object** class itself has a default implementation for the ToString method then you will not have a problem on passing any type of objects including primitives but you may get meaningless representation if the ToString method is not overridden to provide meaningful representation for an object.